# React native moving large code into separate file - is it a hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a react native screen that has a very long code that I would like to refractor.

Say my `screen.jsx` is (simplified, of course):

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import useLocation from '../hooks/useLocation'; // A custom hook I wrote. This one makes sense to use as a hook. It's a function that returns a location.
...

export default function Screen() {
  const [fetchingLocation, region, setRegion] = useLocation();
  
  // FROM HERE DOWN
  const [fetchingRestaurants, setFetchingRestaurants] = useState(false);
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const initSearch = useCallback(async ({ searchQuery, region }) => {
    setFetchingRestaurants(true);
    try {
      const response = await remoteApi.get('/search', {
        params: {
          term: searchQuery,
          latitude: region.latitude,
          longitude: region.longitude,
        },
      });
      const fetchedRestaurants = response.data.businesses;
      const fetchedRestaurantsArray = fetchedRestaurants.map((restaurant) => ({
        id: restaurant.id,
        name: restaurant.name,
      }));
      setRestaurants(fetchedRestaurantsArray);
      setFetchingRestaurants(false);
    } catch (e) {
      setRestaurants([]);
      setFetchingRestaurants(false);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>...</View>
  );
}
```

To better structure my code, I would like to move all the code you see below "FROM HERE DOWN" (`initSearch` as well as the three state management useState hooks above it) into another file and import it.

At the moment I created a custom `useRestaurantSearch` hook in the **hooks** folder like so:

```
export default function useRestaurantSearch() {
  // The code I mentioned goes here
  return [initSearch, errorMessage, restaurants, setRestaurants, fetchingRestaurants];
}
```

Then in my `Screen.jsx` file I import it `import useRestaurantSearch from '../hooks/useRestaurantSearch';` and inside `function Screen()` I grab the `const`s I need with

```
const [
  initSearch,
  errorMessage,
  restaurants,
  setRestaurants,
  fetchingRestaurants,
] = useRestaurantSearch();
```

This works, but I feel like it can be better written and this whole approach seems weird - is it really a custom hook? If it's not a custom hook, does it belong in a util folder as a utility?

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this would be considered a custom hook since according to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#:%7E:text=Custom%20Hooks%20are%20a%20mechanism,of%20it%20are%20fully%20isolated.), custom hooks are just a mechanism to reuse stateful logic.

One thing that could help simplify it is:

- using a library like [TanStack Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/overview) (formerly React Query). You could create a query to fetch the restaurants and then you could use the data and fetchStatus from the query instead of adding them to state.